# Marker hiding after fitBounds in leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

`fitBounds` and `flyToBounds` are very good for changing the bounds of the map of different positions.

The thing is that I have some markers on the map and when I call this function it **sometimes** hides the marker. This happens because it seems like it does not consider the size of the marker, but only the position of the marker!

Like this:

[image]

I tried both giving array of latlng

```
map.flyToBounds(coords, { duration: 1 })
```

But also trying to create markers to see if it considers it

```
const group = L.featureGroup();
group.clearLayers();
coords.forEach((marker) => group.addLayer(L.marker(marker)));
map.flyToBounds(group.getBounds(), { duration: 1 })
```

All of this is using React Leaflet and `import L from "leaflet";`